# Toggle div and its child elements using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, textbox

I am having a Container in which I have a div element which is draggable with a Asp.Net textbox control.And two image buttons for closing and dragging.

Now when I click on the container the div which is draggable with the textbox control should append to (0,0) position of the container it and when I click close button it should close.

Here is what I have and some suggested me good ideas to go further in the previous question asked by me here

[Adding and remove div on click using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916478/adding-and-remove-div-on-click-using-jquery)

I am in dilemma how to add the textbox control to the draggable div to show as it's a server side control.

This is what I'm having now:
http://jsfiddle.net/v8x4P/7/

Here is the code:

```
 <div id="content" style="background-color: #E5E5E5; width: 500px; height: 500px;">
    <div class="demo" style="border-style: dashed; background-color: #CCCCCC">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" BackColor="Transparent" BorderStyle="None"
            autocomplete="off" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
        <div class="left" style="cursor: move">
        </div>
        <div class="right" style="cursor: nw-resize">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$(function () {

        $('.demo').draggable({

            containment: '#content',

            cursor: 'move',

            snap: '#content',

            stop: function () {

                var offset = $(this).offset();

                var xPos = offset.left;

                var yPos = offset.top;

                $('#posX').text('X: ' + xPos);

                $('#posY').text('Y: ' + yPos);
           }
        })

.resizable();

$('.demo').hover(

function () {

$(this).addClass('hoveredon');

},

function () {

    $(this).removeClass('hoveredon').addclass('hoveredoff');

    }
  );
  });
```

CSS:

```
   #TextBox1

        {

            width: 100%;

            height: 100%; /* make the element resize */

        }

        .demo

        {

            width: 150px;

            height: 150px;

            padding: 5px 10px 10px 4px; /* updated padding to make things look better */    
            background-color: #ff8811;

            position: absolute;

            top: 150px;

            left: 300px;

            filter: alpha(opacity=30);

            -moz-opacity: 0.3;

            opacity: 0.3;
            }


        .hoveredon

        {

            filter: alpha(opacity=100);

            -moz-opacity: 1.0;

            opacity: 1.0;

            border-color: blue;

        }





        .hoveredoff

        {

            filter: alpha(opacity=30);

            -moz-opacity: 0.3;

            opacity: 0.3;

            border-color: silver;

        }



        .demo .left

        {

            content: '';

            position: absolute;

            height: 30px;

            width: 30px;

            top: -16px;

            left: -16px;

            background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/30x30/000/fff&text=close);

            background-repeat: no-repeat;

        }

        .demo .right

        {

            position: absolute;

            height: 30px;

            width: 30px;

            bottom: -10px;

            right: -10px;

            background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/30x30/000/fff&text=drag);

            background-repeat: no-repeat;

        }

        *:focus

        {

            outline: none;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to see the problem here. Obviously jsfiddle.net doesn't know what to do with your server side controls so the ASP.NET TextBox isn't rendering as an input element. But it would in a production environment. If I replace your TextBox control with a standard HTML INPUT element it works fine so I don't see any problem with your code, just your deployment.